# objects in array with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i got this error while building an app
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
         in App (at src/index.js:7)
this the response from the api  , i have this problem also i cant render the array as list properly

```
(15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ImagesSearch from './ImagesSearch'
import axios from 'axios'

export class Images extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          searchquery: '',
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({searchquery:e.target.value})
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.images(this.state.searchquery)
        console.log(this.state.searchquery)
    }

    images(query) {
        return axios.get(`https://api.pexels.com/v1/search? 
            query=${query}+query&per_page=15&page=1`, {
              headers: { Authorization: `` }
            }).then(res => {
               console.log(res.data.photos)
               this.setState(prevState => ({
                   data: [res.data.photos]
               }))
               console.log(this.state.data)
               return res.data
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const mapRows = this.state.data.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
                <li>
                    <span>Name : {item.url}</span>
                    <span>User Type: {item.url}</span>
                 </li>
            </div>))

        return (
            <div>
                <form class="form-group m-2" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                   <label>Search</label>
                   <input class="form-control form-control-sm w-25 mx-auto" name="searchquery" type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.onChange}  />
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Submit</button>
                </form>
            <div>
            { mapRows }
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Images
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Your `setState` phase is wrong and that's why you can't render. I updated my answer. Please check my answer what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setState` phase is wrong with `[res.data.photos]`. `res.data.photos` is array value but you also set it as array again. So, the state value will be like this:

```
data: [[{...}, {...}, ..., {...}]]
```

You should use `res.data.photos` instead of `[res.data.photos]`.

```
images(query) {
    ...
           this.setState(prevState => ({
               data: res.data.photos  // your code was [res.data.photos]
           }))
    ...
}
```

Also, you can use `index` instead of `id` if id is duplicated. Try with the following to avoid `Warning`.

```
const mapRows = this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <li>
        <span>Name : {item.url}</span>
        <span>User Type: {item.url}</span>
     </li>
  </div>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you array has duplicate id values or the id property is missing from the objects in your array.

```
const mapRows = this.state.data.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id}> // possible duplicate here
                    <li>
                        <span>Name : {item.url}</span>
                        <span>User Type: {item.url}</span>
                     </li>
                </div>))
```